# In a bash script, how use osascript to minimize all windows of a specific app?

Tags: applescript, bash

The following script opens the named files in the Skim app but fails to minimize them after that. What command will in fact minimize all windows of the app?

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf; do open -a Skim.app ${f}; done;
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Skim" to false'
```

The script will be invoked from zsh (under macOS). Oddly, if I issue at the zsh command prompt the following, then all those windows do get minimized:

```
[~] % bash
[me:~]% osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Skim" to false'
```

So why is the latter command no working directly from within the bash script?

Comment: Hard to say but here are two small things you might try. First, change your script to zsh rather than bash. Second, add a brief delay, e.g. `sleep 2` between the two lines of code.

Comment: I wonder if you have a race condition going on.  Put a `sleep` command after the Skim invocation to give it a chance to establish its windows and see if that makes the **Hide** (not Minimize) work.

Comment: Neither changing the script from bash to zsh nor inserting a  `sleep 2`  command, nor both together,  fixed this. But zsh plus `sleep 5` did!

Comment: That just means you weren't sleeping long enough.  The shell should be irrelevant.